# Issue with list style click on this jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I got to use [this](http://sampathnarsingam.blogspot.in/2012/05/how-to-create-expand-and-collapse-list.html) on one of my site and during the testing, I found that when i click on the image button then it selects the entire li items automatically but this is happening only firefox and chrome and IE is fine. Does any one can help me on this.

You can try on Firefox, when you click on the list image, it selects the main menu and sub menu automatically.

If some one has already worked on this and help me out in finding the issue, I will be thankful.

More info: I tried using as background image for plusimage and minus image, it does not work.
I have used list-style-position: inside, does not work and also with display:inline-block and all other possible stuff

Comment: That's because you're double clicking instead of only clicking once right?

Comment: @ComputerArts, am just clicking once, i tried on multiple systems. If am clicking on the other area except the list-style-image url then its fine, this happens only when I click on + image or - image on the left hand side

Answer (score 0):

Add these properties to .category class in style sheet to make items unselectable:

```
.catgory { 
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none; 
}
```